# How do I remove double ticks (leaving a single set) on a color bar in matplotlib's imshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow, xticks

I'm using this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid
plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = False
import seaborn as sns
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

a = np.random.random((8, 8))
data = pd.DataFrame([[a],[a],[a],[a]])
fig, [[ax1, ax2], [ax3, ax4]] = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize = (14,12) ) 
fig.suptitle('my title', fontsize=20)

im1 = ax1.imshow(data[0][0], cmap='plasma', origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', rasterized=True)
divider1 = make_axes_locatable(ax1) 
cax1 = divider1.append_axes("right", size="20%", pad=0.01)
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(im1)
im2 = ax2.imshow(data[0][1], cmap='plasma', origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', rasterized=True)
divider2 = make_axes_locatable(ax2) 
cax2 = divider2.append_axes("right", size="20%", pad=0.01)
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(im2)
im3 = ax3.imshow(data[0][2], cmap='plasma', origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', rasterized=True)
divider3 = make_axes_locatable(ax3) 
cax3 = divider3.append_axes("right", size="20%", pad=0.01)
cbar3 = fig.colorbar(im3)
im4 = ax4.imshow(data[0][3], cmap='plasma', origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', rasterized=True)
divider4 = make_axes_locatable(ax4) 
cax4 = divider4.append_axes("right", size="20%", pad=0.01)
cbar4 = fig.colorbar(im4)
plt.show()
```

Which is making plots with unusual colorbar ticks (on both sides). How can I get this to look nice or with no numbers on the lefts of the colorbars?
[Plots with extra ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fegow.png)

Comment: Plot the colorbar on the axis you made for it: `fig.colorbar(im1, cax=cax1)` etc. An [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_colorbar_with_axes_divider.html) in the docs

Comment: It is not the same question as redirect states. The comment of @DavidG is useful. The correted code is ```
...
fig, axx = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize = (14,12) ) 
fig.suptitle('my title', fontsize=20)

for iax, ax in enumerate(axx.flatten()):
    im1 = ax.imshow(data[0][0], cmap='plasma', origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', rasterized=True)
    divider1 = make_axes_locatable(ax) 
    cax1 = divider1.append_axes("right", size="20%", pad="1%")
    cbar1 = fig.colorbar(im1, cax=cax1)
```